# Pascal: 201 error

Tags: pascal

i am making a program for storing data for student information(homework)
so.... i made this program but i got a error 201 code!
Also, i cant store the data to the txt file too. Is it because the error too ?
i check 201 error on internet but i have no idea to fix that
i got this error when my array went to 6....
Here's is my program

```
    program arrary1;
var
   studentinfo:text;
   i,a:integer;
   tf:boolean;
   name:array[1..10] of string[25];
   classno:array[1..10] of integer;
   gender:array[1..10] of char;
procedure inputdata;
begin
   i:=1;
   repeat
      write('Enter the name of student: ');
      readln(name[i]);
      if name[i]<>'END'
      then
      begin
         write('Enter the class number of student: ');
         readln(classno[i]);
         write('Enter the gender of student: ');
         readln(gender[i]);
         i:=i+1;
         end
      else begin
      exit;
      end;
      until i=11;
      end;

procedure displaydata;
begin
   for a:= 1 to i-1 do
   begin
   writeln(name[a],' ',classno[a],' ',gender[a]);
   i:=i+1;
   end;
   end;

procedure storedata;
begin
   for a:= 1 to i-1 do
   begin
   assign(studentinfo, 'G:\pascal\studentdata.txt');
   rewrite(studentinfo);
   writeln(studentinfo,name[a],' ',classno[a],' ',gender[a]);
   close(studentinfo);
   i:=i+1;
   end;
   end;
begin
   inputdata;
   displaydata;
   storedata;
end.
```

The checking if `name[i]` is to let the user input END to end the proram
TY FOR ANSWERING !!!!

Comment: I don't think your internet search was very thorough. A Google search of "pascal runtime error 201" quickly yields [this one](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/user/userap4.html) of many possible answers. It means your array index is out of range. *Also, i cant store the data to the txt file too. Is it because the error too ?* Getting a run time error is a very good indicator that you're program is not going to produce the results you want.

Comment: Always compile homework with -Criot to turn on the most important checks

Answer (score 0):

In the procedure `displaydata` you increment the global variable i from 11 to  21, the next loop `a:=1 to  i-1` violates the limits.